# Convergence of $\sum\limits_{k=2}^\infty \frac{|\sin kx|}{\log k}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series

For what values of $x \in \mathbb{R}$ do the series 
$$ \sum\limits_{k=2}^\infty \frac{|\sin kx|}{\log k} $$
converge (and how do you prove the rest diverge)?

The series converge trivially at $x = n\pi$ where $n \in \mathbb{Z}$, but I'm not sure about any others.

Comment: My guess is that it would usually diverge because of the absolute value in the numerator. These would have a typical value of 1/2, so that the sum would diverge even if the denominator were k instead of log k. Maybe Cauchy-Schwarz could help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the case $x \neq n\pi$, we have

$$|\sin(kx)|\geqslant \sin^2(kx)= \frac1{2}[1-\cos(2kx)]$$

and

$$\sum_{k=2}^n \frac{|\sin(kx)|}{\log k} \geqslant \frac1{2}\sum_{k=2}^n \frac{1}{\log k}-\frac1{2}\sum_{k=2}^n \frac{\cos(2kx)}{\log k}.$$

The series does not converge since

$$\sum_{k=2}^\infty \frac{1}{\log k} = \infty$$

and the second sum on the RHS converges by the Dirichlet test.